# removing row header in blueprintjs table

Tags: reactjs, blueprintjs

What is the proper way to remove the row header in blueprintjs table ?

[image: row header]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<Table enableRowHeader={false}>
  ...
</Table>
```

All props can be found here: https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#table/api